# How to avoid JavaScript from clearing form data if user fails validation?

Tags: javascript, html

The below JavaScript code refresh the html page if user enters more than 20 characters in the input box. However i don't want the content of the input boxes to be cleared i want them to stay in the input box even if user fails validation. Other than using OnSubmit in form is there a way to avoid the page from clearing data ?

```
<form >

Enter your e-mail address:   <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
Enter your Name/Username :  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="validate()">  

</form>
```

.

```
function validate(){

 var x= document.getElementById("email").value;
 var y= document.getElementById("username").value;      

 var n =y.length;  


if(n > 20){

alert("Oops Username Greater than 20 characters ");

}

else{

// redirecting to a diffrent page

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to bind the handler to the `submit` event?

Comment: Why refresh the page when the input is invalid?

Comment: Are we talking client or server side validation or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form via ajax rather than a form post.  The ajax call will not change the page contents so if your form doesn't pass validation on the server, you still have the all the form elements the user entered exactly as they entered them.  If the ajax call does succeed, you can redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error in the form, store the user's value in a variable, and use `getElementById("elementName").value=variableName;`
Which will make it persistant.

Comment: Why the refresh? It seems he doesn't know about onclick="return validate()" - the RETURN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a persistant storage solution, such as cookies or userdata.
Userdata is easier to manipulate and can store alot more than a cookie.
This is how I set, get and delete userdata:

code:

```
function DATAget(name){return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));}//load[name]
function DATAset(name,value){localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));}//save[name,value]
function DATAdel(name){localStorage.removeItem(name);}//delete[name]
```

usage:

```
DATAset("username", $('#username').val()); //set username
$('#username').val(DATAget("username")); // retrieve username
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

### Use "onChange" method in your input box

```
&lt;input type="text" name="username" id="username" onChange="isLessThen20()"&gt;
```

<script>
   function isLessThen20() { 
       var y = document.getElementById("username");
       var n = y.length;
     if(n>20){
           alert("Oops Username Greater than 20 characters ");
      }
     else{
         //redirect to some other page 
     }

```
 }
```

<script>

Comment: this script would fire the else function right away. rather than onChange, perhaps onBlur would be better suited to this answer